# Im trying to implement authentication in next.js using next-auth and next.js middleware, but im getting an error when using it in every route

Tags: node.js, next.js, next-auth

Im trying to implement auth logic using this [example](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth-example/blob/main/middleware.ts) but I am trying to implement it in every route like so

```
export const config = {
  matcher: ['/:path*'],
};
```

but my browser breaks because too many requests, but when I change the matcher array to specific routes, it works, like this:

```
 matcher: ['/teacher','/student'],
```

with the matcher like this, auth works for the pages (student,teacher) but not other pages.

middleware.ts:

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { withAuth } from 'next-auth/middleware';

const PUBLIC_FILE = /\.(.*)$/;

export default withAuth(
  async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
    if (
      req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/_next') ||
      req.nextUrl.pathname.includes('/api/') ||
      PUBLIC_FILE.test(req.nextUrl.pathname)
    ) {
      return;
    }

    if (req.nextUrl.locale === 'default') {
      const locale = req.cookies.get('NEXT_LOCALE') || 'en';

      return NextResponse.rewrite(
        new URL(
          `/${locale}${req.nextUrl.pathname}${req.nextUrl.search}`,
          req.url,
        ),
      );
    }
  },
  {
    callbacks: {
      authorized({ req, token }) {
        return !!token;
      },
    },
  },
);

export const config = {
  matcher: ['/:path*', '/teacher'],
};
```